# Screenplay writing with Lyx - problems with default classes

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts, screenplay

I love lyx and want to use it for screenplay writing. Two layouts are included and the classes (broadway.cls and hollywood.cls) I have downloaded. I kept them in the same directory as the lyx file and there are always errors coming. So my question is: Where do I need to put the classes (on my mac)?

What other options for screenplay writing besides the mentioned, do I have?

Note: I checked all lyx-site sources and comments on it, which didn't solve my questions.

Error messages:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.5.24)  27 JUN 2016 21:58
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**newfile1.tex
(./newfile1.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.

(/Users/matthiasbrust/Dropbox/hollywood.cls

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.1 <
     script>window.googleJavaScriptRedirect=1

You're in trouble here.  Try typing    to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X   to quit.

Missing character: There is no < in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
etc.

Comment: Welcome on TeX.SE! Could you please provide us some error messages?

Comment: That is what I get when the cls is in the same path as the lyx file.

Comment: Try the steps from "Templates on the Mac" further down this page: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MacInstall

Comment: @alwaysask Thank you very much. That helped. Please note, the path is a bit different and the instructions aren't so straight forward! But again that helped. I think they need to update the site. Maybe you might want to give your comment as answer to the question?

Comment: I think it would be better for *you* to give the answer to this question with the steps you followed to solve the issue. Because: that page is 5 years old and I have no credit for it, I've only touched a Mac once in my life, started with `lyx` but I moved away within a month. I just googled for a solution as I remembered similar issues I had, solved by telling `lyx` about changes (but forgot how --> Edit > Reconfigure).